# How can I read posts from Twitter?

Tags: asp.net, api, twitter, oauth, asp.net-3.5

On my site I've got a section which displays the latest tweets from my twitter account. I used Twitterizer to read latest tweets from my account and bind them to a `Repeater`

However, with Twitter's new security, I can't use this as I must use oAuth.

What is the best way of returning tweets from an account?

Comment: You can try [this](http://deepumi.wordpress.com/2010/08/03/twitter-tweets-in-asp-net-c/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you upgrade to Twitterizer2? See website note here: http://code.google.com/p/twitterizer/

Comment: It's not as simple as updating as the Twitterizer2 uses oAuth and is a lot more complicated.

Comment: but OAuth is what you need; it's the only authorisation mechanism allowed for twitter now as far as I know.

Comment: Good point @Jomas, looks like I'm just going to have to spend some time looking into it!